# Uncaught Error: Call to a member function get_cart() on null

Tags: woocommerce

On Woocommerce, I have an error message on my function but i don't unserstand why it happens.

Uncaught Error: Call to a member function get_cart() on null in ...
The function checks id a category product is in the cart.

The error is displayed in the order detail in backend

It's used in functions.php , executed on checkout page, 
called by these hooks: 
woocommerce_before_order_notes
woocommerce_checkout_process
woocommerce_checkout_update_order_meta
woocommerce_admin_order_data_after_billing_address
woocommerce_email_order_meta_keys

https://i.stack.imgur.com/v7Atp.png

```
function is_in_the_cart() {

    $found=false;

// Find if product is in the cart price <=40
    foreach( WC()->cart->get_cart() as $cart_item_key => $values )
 {
        $cart_product = $values['data'];
        $price = accessProtected($values['data'], 'changes')['price'];
        if ($price >=40 && $cart_product->id=='969') {$found=true;}
  }


if ( $found ) {
        return true;
    } else {
        return false;
    }
}



     add_action('woocommerce_checkout_process', 'wps_select_checkout_field_process');
     function wps_select_checkout_field_process() {
         if (is_in_the_cart())
    {
        global $woocommerce;

        // Check if set, if its not set add an error.
        if ($_POST['dvd'] == "blank")
         wc_add_notice( '<strong>Merci de séléctionner un DVD</strong>', 'error' );
    }
     }

     //* Update the order meta with field value
     add_action('woocommerce_checkout_update_order_meta', 'wps_select_checkout_field_update_order_meta');
     function wps_select_checkout_field_update_order_meta( $order_id ) {
         if (is_in_the_cart())
    {
       if ($_POST['dvd']) update_post_meta( $order_id, 'dvd', esc_attr($_POST['dvd']));
    }
     }


     add_action( 'woocommerce_admin_order_data_after_billing_address', 'wps_select_checkout_field_display_admin_order_meta', 10, 1 );
    function wps_select_checkout_field_display_admin_order_meta($order){
         if (is_in_the_cart())
    {
        echo '<p><strong>DVD: </strong> ' . get_post_meta( $order->id, 'dvd', true ) . '</p>';
    }
    }

    //* Add selection field value to emails
    add_filter('woocommerce_email_order_meta_keys', 'wps_select_order_meta_keys');
    function wps_select_order_meta_keys( $keys ) {
         if (is_in_the_cart())
    {
        $keys['Dvd:'] = 'dvd';
        return $keys;
        }
    }
```

Comment: where do you use that code? At what time do you show the result? on which page? with which hook?

Comment: OK Question edited

Answer (score 3):

I think you want to check to make sure the cart isn't empty before your function.

Also... You can access price by using `get_price()` from the product object which you are retrieving with `$values['data']`

```php
    function is_in_the_cart(){

        // Make sure it's only on front end
        if (is_admin()) return false;

        $found = false;

        // If cart is empty - bail and return false
        if (empty (WC()->cart->get_cart())) {  

            return false;

        } else {

        foreach ( WC()->cart->get_cart() as $cart_item_key => $values ) {
            $cart_product = $values[ 'data' ];
            // Find if product is in the cart price <=40
            $price = floatval($cart_product->get_price());
            if ( $price >= 40 && $cart_product->id == '969' ) {
                $found = true;
                }
            }

            if ( $found ) {
                return true;
            } else {
                return false;
            }
        }
    }
```

**UPDATED** - added `is_admin` to prevent from running on backend.

Comment: thanks for the empty condition. About get_price it's not the good attribute because i use WC name your price and the price is dynamic, So i keep my method to get it.

Comment: Is empty() a better solution than is_null () ?

Comment: `get_cart() Returns the contents of the cart in an array. woocommerce/includes/class-wc-cart.php:604` so null isn't what is returned.

Comment: so better to use empty () ?

Comment: when i had the error cart was not empty because order has been completed

Comment: actually the error happens in the order detail in backend

Comment: I updated answer.  This prevents the WC()->cart object from being called in the admin and will prevent the error from happening on backend.

Comment: actually i don't think so...i have removed if (is_in_the_cart()) in the hook , to hide the error